# Golang RWMutex on map content edit

Tags: dictionary, go, mutex

I'm starting to use `RWMutex` in my Go project with `map` since now I have more than one routine running at the same time and while making all of the changes for that a doubt came to my mind.

The thing is that I know that we must use `RLock` when only reading to allow other routines to do the same task and `Lock` when writing to full-block the map. But what are we supposed to do when editing a previously created element in the map?

For example... Let's say I have a `map[int]string` where I do `Lock`, put inside `"hello "` and then `Unlock`. What if I want to add `"world"` to it? Should I do `Lock` or can I do `RLock`?

Comment: There are two kinds of operations, reads and writes. Editing a value is a write operation, not a read operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should approach the problem from another angle.

A simple rule of thumb you seem to understand just fine is

> You need to protect the map from *concurrent accesses* when at least one of them is a *modification.*

Now the real question is what constitutes a modification of a map.

To answer it properly, it helps to notice that *values stored in maps are not addressable* — by design.
This was engineered that way simply due to the fact maps internally have intricate implementation which
[might move values they contain in memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation)
to provide (amortized) fast access time
when the map's structure changes due to insertions and/or deletions of its elements.

The fact map values are not addressable means you *can not* do
something like

```
m := make(map[int]string)
m[42] = "hello"
go mutate(&m[42]) // take a single element and go modifying it...
// ...while other parts of the program change _other_ values
m[123] = "blah blah"
```

The reason you are not allowed to do this is the
insertion operation `m[123] = ...` might trigger moving
the storage of the map's element around, and that might
involve moving the storage of the element keyed by `42`
to some other place in memory — pulling the rug
from under the feet of the goroutine
running the `mutate` function.

So, in Go, maps really only support three operations:

- Insert — or replace — an element;
- Read an element;
- Delete an element.

You cannot modify an element "in place" — you can only
go in three steps:

1. Read the element;
2. Modify the variable containing the (read) copy;
3. Replace the element by the modified copy.

As you can now see, the steps (1) and (3) are mere map accesses,
and so the answer to your question is (hopefully) apparent:
the step (1) shall be done under at least an read lock,
and the step (3) shall be done under a write (exclusive) lock.

---

In contrast, elements of other compound types —
arrays (and slices) and fields of `struct` types —
do not have the restriction maps have: provided the storage
of the "enclosing" variable is not relocated, it is fine to
change its different elements concurrently by different goroutines.

Answer (score 2):

Since the only way to change the value associated with the key in the map is to reassign the changed value to the same key, that is a write / modification, so you have to obtain the write lock–simply using the read lock will not be sufficient.